# How to automate 100 users in jmeter using rest api

Tags: jmeter

I have a rest GET api `http://hostname/get_userid/{userid}`. I have 100 users in .csv file. like below

```
userid
user1
user2
user3
user4 
.
.
.
.
```

Now when {userid} gets replaced by every username from .csv file the api returns details of that user. which will be asserted with status code for every user. How to automate this scenario?

Also when i parameterize the above api like below

```
servername : hostname
Path : /get_userid/
```

and in send parameters with request

```
Name = userid
Value = ${userid}
```

i am getting the request response as http://hostname/get_userid/?userid=user1 and

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback
```

as error instead http://hostname/get_userid/user1 which is a correct request which returns a json object.

Comment: add ${userid} to path field instead of adding it as a parameter

Comment: Thanks, it worked for 1 user when i add ${userid} in path directly. How to get for 100 users which are in .csv file ? i Have added CSV data config from config elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashu,

Please enter the 'userid' variable in the path as mentioned below:

- Path : /get_userid/${userid}

Additionally, use the [CSV data set config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element of JMeter to get the userids from .csv file and further use it in the script through variable name. Please follow below steps:

1. Create .csv file and enter userids separate by newline:
     user1
     user2
     .
     .
2. Add 'CSV Data Set Config' element in your script
3. Set CSV Data Set Config element fields as mentioned in the screenshot:[image]

For more information on CSV Data Set config, please to the blog post: [Automated Load Testing with Unique Users](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users/)